# Checking for sum of primes

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below checks whether a given integer can be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers:

```
def sum_of_primes(num):
  isPrime = 1
  for i in range (2,int(num/2)+1):
    if(num % i == 0):
        isPrime = 0
        break
  return isPrime

num = [int(n) for n in input("Input the numbers: ").split()]

flag = 0
i = 2
for z in num:
  for i in range (2,int(z/2)+1):
    if(sum_of_primes(z) == 1):
      if(sum_of_primes(z-i) == 1):
         print(z,"can be expressed as a sum of",i,"and",z-i)
         flag = 1;
  if (flag == 0):
    print(z,"cannot be expressed as a sum of primes")
```

However, I did not get the expected result: if I enter `[12 4 5]` it returns:

```
12 cannot be expressed as a sum of primes
4 can be expressed as a sum of 2 and 2
5 can be expressed as a sum of 2 and 3
```

and its wrong because 12 can be expressed as `7 + 5`. Should be working for every even number greater than 2.

If the input is `[5 4 12]` it returns:

```
5 can be expressed as a sum of 2 and 3
4 can be expressed as a sum of 2 and 2
```

omitting the 12.

Comment: Obviously now `num` is a list and not a single number. You now need to do something like `for x in num` and then keep with the same code. Will be more reasonable to do `for num in nums`...

Comment: So, you've change this line `num = int(input("Enter a number : "))` which used to return a single number, to `num = [int(n) for n in input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split()]` which by your own admission creates a list. Now the interpreter is telling you that it cannot divide a list.

Comment: So think about what you already have -- a function that can check if a single number fulfils certain criteria; and a list of numbers. Instead of passing the entire list to your function, pass each integer in the list!

Comment: i did use a `for x in num` but i keep getting the same error.  I thought that the `int(n)` would be enough to convert the input from string to int, guess i am wrong..

Comment: You're not wrong. It converts a list of strings to a list of ints. But you still have a list! Update your code with the relevant version, the one creating the list and we will be able to help. We need a [mre], we can't guess

Comment: ok. Just edited the code with the last version, still not working properly. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function which returns the number smaller than the sum or zero:

```
def sum_of_prime(n):
    sieve5m6 = [True] * (n//6+1)
    sieve1m6 = [True] * (n//6+1)
    for i in range(1,int((n**0.5+1)/6)+1):
        if sieve5m6[i]:
            sieve5m6[6*i*i::6*i-1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i)//(6*i-1)+1)
            sieve1m6[6*i*i-2*i::6*i-1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i+2*i)//(6*i-1)+1)
        if sieve1m6[i]:
            sieve5m6[6*i*i::6*i+1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i)//(6*i+1)+1)
            sieve1m6[6*i*i+2*i::6*i+1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i-2*i)//(6*i+1)+1)
    if n%6==0 and n>6:
        sumbool=[a and b for a, b in zip(sieve5m6[1:-1:], sieve1m6[-2:0:-1])]
        if sumbool.count(True)>0:
            return 6*(sumbool.index(True)+1)-1
        else:
            return 0
    elif n%6==2 and n>6:
        if sieve5m6[n//6]==True:
            return 3
        else:
            sumbool=[a and b for a, b in zip(sieve1m6[1:(n//6)//2+1:], sieve1m6[-2:(n//6)-(n//6)//2-1:-1])]
            if sumbool.count(True)>0:
                return 6*(sumbool.index(True)+1)+1
            else:
                return 0
    elif n%6==4 and n>6:
        if sieve1m6[n//6]==True:
            return 3
        else:
            sumbool=[a and b for a, b in zip(sieve5m6[1:(n//6)//2+1:], sieve5m6[-1:(n//6)-(n//6)//2:-1])]  
            if sumbool.count(True)>0:
                return 6*(sumbool.index(True)+1)-1
            elif sieve5m6[(n//6)//2+1]==True and (n//6)%2==1:
                return 6*((n//6)//2+1)-1
            else:
                return 0

    else:
        if n==4 or n==5:
            return 2
        if n==6:
            return 3
        elif sieve1m6[n//6]==True and n%6==3 and n>3:
            return 2
        elif sieve5m6[n//6]==True and n%6==1 and n>1:
            return 2
        else:
            return 0
```

This is the code to use it:

```
n=100
p=sum_of_prime(n)
if p > 0:
    print(n,"can be expressed as a sum of",p,"and",n-p)
else:
    print(n,"cannot be expressed as a sum of primes")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not required to produce the actual primes but only test if there exists a pair of primes p and q such that p+q == N, you could make this very simple based on the Goldbach conjecture. All even numbers can be expressed as the sum of two primes. So return True if the number is even and check if N-2 is prime for odd numbers (because 2 is the only even prime and that's the only prime that will produce another odd number when starting from an odd number). This will boil down to a single prime test of N-2 only for odd numbers.

```
def primePart(N):
    return N>3 and (N%2==0 or all((N-2)%p for p in range(3,int(N**0.5)+1,2)))

primePart(3432)  # True

primePart(37+2)  # True

primePart(13+41) # True

primePart(123)   # False
```

If you do need to find the actual primes, then you can use the sieve of Eratosthenes to map primes up to N and sequentially check pairs:

```
def primePart(N):
    isPrime = [0,0,1]+[1,0]*(N//2)      # sieve of Eratosthenes
    for p in range(3,int(N**0.5)+1,2):  # ... √N finds all primes up to N
        if isPrime[p]: isPrime[p*p::p] = [0]*len(isPrime[p*p::p])

    if N%2: return (2,N-2) if isPrime[N-2] else None # Odd number: prime + 2

    for p in range(3,N//2+1,2):  # find pair for even number
        if isPrime[p] and isPrime[N-p]: return (p,N-p)

print(primePart(3432))  # (19, 3413)

print(primePart(37+2))  # (2, 37)

print(primePart(13+41)) # (7, 43)

print(primePart(123))   # None
```